# Fail to authenticate REST API with PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

API need me to use the HTTP header to authenticate every POST request. But I receive "fail to authenticate" as a response for every time. (Please help me, this is my very first time deal with REST API )I provided with documentation that told me to do so:

1. Concatenate all the elements ++++
2. Hash it with HMAC-SHA1 and the Secret Key.
3. Encode terminal code and signature to base64 format.
4. Combine all with scheme, terminal code and signature and assign to authorization
5. Connect the server with authorization

   ```
   function callAPI($method,$url,$data,$dt,$auth){
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method){
       case "POST":
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          if ($data)
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
          break;
       case "PUT":
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
          if ($data)
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
          break;
       default:
          if ($data)
             $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //Set the all the data inside the header
    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $header[] = 'Authorization: '.$auth;
    $header[] = 'Date-Time: '.$dt;

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($curl);
   ```

   }

Comment: Are you trying to call shopify api?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell which API I call